# Open Devices and printers window in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, controlpanel

How do I open the `Devices and printers` tab in the `control panel` with `batch` or from the `command prompt`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the [CLSID Key (GUID) listing](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/13591-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts-list-windows-8-a.html).

With shell, you can execute code to open the control panel to the desired location.

```
explorer shell:::{CLSID key number below}
```

In this case, your code would be:

```
explorer shell:::{A8A91A66-3A7D-4424-8D24-04E180695C7A}
```

---

Alternatively:

Open Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound, left click and drag `Devices and Printers` to the desktop, this will create a new shortcut to that location.

[image]

With the shortcut, you can run it within a command prompt or a shell alternative.

[image]

---

Both methods do the exact thing, opening the lnk in notepad reveals the location of:

```
{ 2 6 E E 0 6 6 8 - A 0 0 A - 4 4 D 7 - 9 3 7 1 - B E B 0 6 4 C 9 8 6 8 3 } \ 2 \ : : { A 8 A 9 1 A 6 6 - 3 A 7 D - 4 4 2 4 - 8 D 2 4 - 0 4 E 1 8 0 6 9 5 C 7 A }
```

Comment: Does this work for different languages? One single shortcut and does it work for xp and 7?

Comment: Yes it works on Windows XP. This will work for any language that can communicate with shell. For example, PHP's [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

Comment: If you want a more concrete approach (one that does not require a file to be created), you can check out the edit.

Answer (score 5):

Simple Run or CMD Command:

```
control printers
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the Control Panel apps in Windows that are using an Explorer UI can actually be launched quite easily as so:

```
control /name Microsoft.<name_of_app>
```

For example, you can do this:

```
control /name Microsoft.DevicesAndPrinter
control /name Microsoft.Display
```

Also, using rundll32.exe is another common way to open *.cpl apps. But that is a bit trickier and cryptic. Here's how you could open the Playback Devices view in the Sounds control panel:

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL mmsys.cpl,,playback
```